# How do you selectively remove models from a Backbone collection and from the server?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

For example, if you want to remove the completed todos from a todo list.

Selectively removing models from a Backbone collection and server seems like a common task. What are the common ways to do it, and what are the costs and benefits associated with each way?

Comment: I think there's no way around calling `sync()` after either `reset()` or `set()`

Comment: @ivarni I thought that `sync()` only supports `read` for collections?  `The second argument, model, is a Backbone.Model or Backbone.Collection – collections are used when reading multiple values.` - http://dailyjs.com/2012/12/06/backbone-tutorial-2/. If so, to use `sync()` you'd have to customize it to do the things I discuss in my answer.

Comment: I just had a quick look in the source and it looked like it would but I didn't have time to test it, hence posting as a comment :)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution One**

```
var toRemove = collection.filter(function(model) {
  return condition(model);
});
_.invoke(toRemove, 'destroy');
```

This seems like the cleanest way. It's what Addy [used](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#application-view) in his book to delete completed todos (which is a big reason why I list this solution first). It's especially clean if you're reusing the filter function (like he is).

However, I think it's slower than Solution Two because it involves iteration over `collection` and `toRemove`, whereas Solution Two only involves iteration over `collection`. Still, they both have linear run times so it's not too big a deal.

---

**Solution Two**

```
for (var i = collection.models.length-1; i >= 0; i--) { // looping from back to front
  var model = collection.models[i];
  if (condition(model)) model.destroy();
}
```

I think this is relatively clean. And as mentioned above, this has the benefit of only having to loop through the collection, not the collection + a filtered version of the collection.

It's important that you loop from back to front. Consider what happens when you loop from front to back:

```
for (var i = 0; i < collection.models.length; i++) { // looping from front to back
  var model = this.models[i];
  if (condition(model)) {
    model.destroy();
    i--;
  }
}
```

When you destroy a model, the models in `collection.models` basically get shifted up by one. This has two implications:

1. The length of the array decreases by one.
2. Say you delete element two. The next element will be four, not three. The index gets incremented to 3, and since the models get shifted up by one, three has an index of 2 and four has an index of 3.

Solutions:

1. Calculate `collection.models.length` after each iteration of the loop. Ie. `for (var i = 0; i < **collection.models.length**; i++)`
2. Decrement `i` after you destroy a model.

You could loop from front to back, but you would just have to address these things, which makes it a bit more complicated.

---

**Solution Three**

```
var toRemove = [];
collection.forEach(function(model) {
  if (condition(model)) toRemove.push(model);
});
toRemove.forEach(function(model) {
  model.destroy();
});
```

This is pretty similar to Solution One.

Differences:

1. We're using a `forEach` to construct `toRemove` instead of `filter`.
2. We're manually iterating through and calling `destroy` instead of using `invoke`.

Like Solution One, you have to iterate through `collection` and through `toRemove`, and so it presumably takes longer than Solution Two.

Note: we can't destroy the model in the first `forEach` loop. If we do, then it has the same problem as the front-to-back loop in Solution Two. To get around this limitation, we have to use the `toRemove` array.

---

**Solution Four**

This uses `reset()` + the `reset` event.

```
var toKeep = collection.filter(function(model) {
  return condition(model);
});
collection.reset(toKeep);
```

and

```
collection.on('reset', function(after, before) {
  // let after.length = k
  // let before.length = n
  after.sort(); // k*logk
  for (var i = before.length-1; i >= 0; i--) { // n
    var model = before[i];
    if (!binarySearch(model, after)) model.remove(); // logk
  }
  // total runtime: n*logk + k*logk
});
```

This seems a bit excessive to me, but is an option.